# Remove row if certain variable is the same as the row above

Tags: r, dataframe

I will build on this question Similar to [Remove Rows From Data Frame where a Row match a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650510/remove-rows-from-data-frame-where-a-row-match-a-string)

For example:

```
A,B,org.id
4,3,Foo
2,3,Bar
2,4,Bar
7,5,Zap
7,4,Zap
7,3,Zap
```

How would I return a dataframe that excludes all rows where org.id is the same as the row above?

```
A,B,org.id
4,3,Foo
2,3,Bar
7,5,Zap
```

Guess: Perhaps melt() or cast() functions could do the trick. (I only know how to do this in excel, where I have to create a new dataframe and do *IF[a2=a1,0,a2]*.)

The question is also similar to [Subtract the previous row of data where the id is the same as the row above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232228/subtract-the-previous-row-of-data-where-the-id-is-the-same-as-the-row-above) but that is in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `duplicated`

```
 df1[!duplicated(df1$org.id),]
 #   A B org.id
 #1 4 3    Foo
 #2 2 3    Bar
 #4 7 5    Zap
```

Or using `unique` with `by` option

```
 library(data.table)
 unique(setDT(df1), by='org.id')
```

Comment: I tried **head((dff_all2[duplicated(dff_all2$id), c(1,4,6,17)]))**

# but it outputs:

    country_id       id             device_model channel
177         BR  776962     iPhone5,1 (iPhone 5) Organic
189         BR  687574         GT-I9505 samsung     SEM
310         BR 1037119          XT1058 motorola Organic
439         BR  735454        GT-I8190L samsung Organic
805         BR  779030        GT-S5360B samsung  Direct
852         BR  661698 iPhone3,1 (iPhone 4 GSM)  Direct

Comment: @jacob My code was based on the example you showed.  Please update your post with a new example (preferably with `dput`) that causes the anomaly.